# Create, Delete or append CSV - C# or SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, export-to-csv

I have created a query that generates a CSV file (it isn't working properly at the moment), but I need to update it every 15 minutes. I see this being done by either appending the data or deleting the CSV and then rewriting it with all relevant data. The data is from a table that is updated every 15 minutes from a stored procedure. The file name cannot change.

I have been reading that you cannot delete or append a CSV file using SQL, be that BCP or any other means.

Is the appropriate way to write a service in C# to do this or is there a way to do it in SQL. I am not convinced my query is correct either.

My query is:

```
DECLARE @_FilePath NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @_FileName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @_SerialNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @_OutputPath NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    SerialNumber NVARCHAR(75),
    CustomerName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Processed BIT,
    FolderLocation NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
    SELECT d.SerialNumber, d.CustomerName, 0, f.folderLocation 
    FROM Staging.Device d
    INNER JOIN Staging.FtpFolders f ON d.CustomerName = f.CustomerName     

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp WHERE Processed = 0) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @_SerialNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 SerialNumber FROM #tmp 
                          WHERE Processed = 0 AND SerialNumber IS NOT NULL)

    SELECT TOP 1 @_FilePath = FolderLocation 
    FROM #tmp 
    WHERE Processed = 0 AND SerialNumber = @_SerialNumber

    SELECT @_FileName = CONVERT(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))

    SET @_OutputPath = @_FilePath + '\' + @_FileName + '.csv'

    UPDATE #tmp 
    SET Processed = 1 
    WHERE SerialNumber = @_SerialNumber         

    SELECT @_OutputPath

    DECLARE @ExportSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);               

    SET @ExportSQL = N'EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT * FROM [Staging].[PivotedData15]" queryout "' + @_OutputPath + '" -T -c -t -S '''              
END 

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: Do it simply using C# itself. Linq To SQL and Linq To CSV might be your friends.

Comment: @CetinBasoz thanks for that, I feel much more comfortable doing this with C#.